# How to add increment to the mysql php results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm displaying 8 rows from my MySql table, and I'm wondering how I can add numbers in front of each result, like increments 1. - 8. ?

Here's my MySql query line:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT score,pid from score ORDER BY score ASC) As temp GROUP BY temp.pid ORDER BY temp.score ASC LIMIT 8");
```

Comment: use a counter in your loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **PHP** you can do something like this:

```
$i = 1;
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT score,pid from score ORDER BY score ASC) As temp GROUP BY temp.pid ORDER BY temp.score ASC LIMIT 8");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo "<tr>
              <td>". $i ."</td>
              <td>". $row['field'] ."</td>
              <td>". $row['another_field'] ."</td>
              <td>". $row['another_field'] ."</td> 
         </tr>";

    $i += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 as row_number, temp.* 
FROM 
(
   SELECT score,pid 
   from score 
   ORDER BY score ASC
) As temp, (select @rank := 0) r 
GROUP BY temp.pid 
ORDER BY temp.score ASC 
LIMIT 8
```

Comment: Nice solution. Can you explain what is meant by the `(select @rank := 0) r`  of the next `FROM`

Comment: `(select @rank := 0) r` is a trick to introduce and initialize a variable (`@rank`) in a query. That way you don't have to define it before the query seperately.

Comment: Yup this is a very nice way to do it, I use this method all the time too for this type of thing. Takes the hassle out of the server-side code - everything like this helps when building good optimised code :)

Comment: I have no idea how to use it to be honest.

Comment: `@rank := @rank + 1` adds 1 to the value of `@rank` for every row. `as row_number` gives that column a name which is row_number. `(select @rank := 0) r ` initializes the `@rank` variable.

Comment: BTW your query can probably be simplyfied on second look. ordering twice and grouping and such...